# How to put text in images in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm making an app, so I need to know how can I put some text in images.
I'm working with Xcode 7 and Swift 2

I already have this code, but it's in Objective-C and I don't know if it works...

```
- (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

    CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    [img drawInRect:aRectangle];

    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    NSInteger fontSize = 14;
    if ( [text length] > 200 ) {
        fontSize = 10;
    }
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: fontSize];

    [text drawInRect : aRectangle
            withFont : font
       lineBreakMode : UILineBreakModeTailTruncation
           alignment : UITextAlignmentCenter ];

    UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return theImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried translating the code to Swift 2. This is as close as I got:

```
extension UIImage {
    func withText(text: String) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        drawInRect(rectangle)

        UIColor.redColor().set()
        let fontSize = text.characters.count > 200 ? 10 : 14
        let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(CGFloat(fontSize))

        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font
        ]
        (text as NSString).drawInRect(rectangle, withAttributes: attributes)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

As you can see `NSString`'s `drawInRect` now takes a `[String: AnyObject]?` for its attributes. I was not able to find the corresponding keys for `lineBreakMode` and `alignment`.

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect:withAttributes:) states:

> These are the same attributes that can be applied to an `NSAttributedString` object...

---

## Update:

I have added the other specifications:

```
extension UIImage {
    func withText(text: String) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        drawInRect(rectangle)

        let fontSize = text.characters.count > 200 ? 10 : 14
        let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(CGFloat(fontSize))

        let paragraphAttributes = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphAttributes.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
        paragraphAttributes.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphAttributes
        ]
        (text as NSString).drawInRect(rectangle, withAttributes: attributes)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
        return image
    }
}
```

And just incase this was unclear before... This is how you would use the method:

```
// `someImage` is an optional `UIImage` (`UIImage?`), as the initializer is failable
let someImage = UIImage(named: "something.png")

// `imageWithText` is of type `UIImage` here
if let image = someImage {
    let imageWithText = someImage.withText("Hello World")
}

// `imageWithText` is of type `UIImage?` here
let imageWithText = someImage?.withText("Hello World")
```

Comment: Thanks, but i tried the code and it doesn't work...
What i'm trying to do is put some text in any image...
Can you help me in that???
Thank you!!!

Comment: Added an update. I have tried it in a playground and it works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!!!
And, how can i change the size of the text to be more bigger???

Comment: Depends on how you want it. At the moment you set it to be of size `14` (or `10` if there are more than 200 characters).  
I could try to make it a certain width proportional to the picture (between 0% and 100%), by adding a proportionalWidth parameter to the function, if you would like that? Or I could allow you to pass in a `UIFont`, which would allow more customization.

Comment: I would like it to be proportional to the size of the image. Depending on the size of the image, I want the text is centered and proportionate to the size of the image.
Beforehand, thank you very much!!!!!